# Getting error "Stage <repoName> skipped due to earlier failure(s)"

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

Description:In production when was running a jenkins pipeline with set of few jobs it was failing at 2nd stage with above error.

The task of this job is to create a github repository.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:
At the stage where job was failing it was prompting a form or run time prompt to enter the data which was not filled by the user so it was failing with this error. 
Upon executing jobs at console it produces something like:

```
> git checkout -f 4dfa1dc42ea3727a972a81aead8129ab65564208
 > git rev-list --no-walk 4dfa1dc42ea3727a972a81aead8129ab65564208 # timeout=10 [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] withEnv [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Collecting Infrastructure details) [Pipeline] container [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] script [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] sh
+ git --version git version 2.1.4 [Pipeline] input Input requested Approved by Pankaj Gupta (CompuCom) [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // script [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // container [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Collecting ServiceNow details) [Pipeline] container [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] script [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] input Input requested [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // script [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // container [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Display Setup) Stage "Display Setup" skipped due to earlier failure(s) [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Validate Inputs) Stage "Validate Inputs" skipped due to earlier failure(s) [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Create Repo And Add Collaborators) Stage "Create Repo And Add Collaborators" skipped due to earlier failure(s) [Pipeline] }
```

**So if you look at the output then there are two time a URL is called which is "Input requested", when click this hyperlink it gives a new form to fill the request values, if that will not be filled it will give error.**